# Size of view in mm programmatically in android

Tags: java, android, xml, button, size

I want to programmatically set the size of some `View` in **mm** instead of **dp** in android.

Although it is easier to do in `xml` but I need to do it Java.

Can some one help me out. I am stuck.

Comment: you mean pixel (px) not mm I guess?

Comment: no i need mm. Actually i have to print the views on paper and due to different resolution dp gives different size and solution is to use view size in mm. I tried it by giving size  from xml and it worked fine for me but now i have to do it programmatically and not getting any solution to how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

A dp is 1/160th of an inch.  So 1dp is .16 mm (.158 if you need a bit more accuracy).  Dp exists so that its the same size across resolutions, its basically physically sizing things.

Comment: Thanks sir for your precious time. This information is also useful for me.